# What is an example of an extproc.ora file?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, configuration, listener

What do the contents of `extproc` file look like? I'm aware that my `extproc.ora` file is missing, and I'd like to create one in it's absence.

The instructions [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/configure-oracle-extproc.htm) tell me to:

> Configure the Oracle extproc.ora to point to the location of the
>   ST_Geometry library file.
>
> Make a backup copy of the extproc.ora file on the Oracle server. Open
>   the extproc.ora file and alter it to point to the location of the
>   **st_shapelib.dll** (Windows) or libst_shapelib.so (Linux or UNIX)
>   library.
>
> The following line is added
>   to extrproc.ora to point to the ST_Geometry library in that directory:
>
> SET EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\mylibraries\st_shapelib.dll
>
> Save and close the extproc.ora file.

I've tried creating an `extproc.ora` file from scratch, but I don't really know what I'm doing: `SET EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\mylibraries\st_shapelib.dll`.

Not surprisingly, the file fails.

Rather than just dream up what I *think* the file should contain, I'd like to copy an existing example. I've searched the web, but have not come up with any complete examples of `extproc.ora`. Not even in the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/advcfg.htm#NETAG0133

What is an example of an extproc.ora file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\hs\admin*</sup>

Frankly, I never got my homemade **`exproc.ora`** working with the `st‌​_shapelib.dll` library:

The `extproc.ora` file contains this text: `SET EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\mylibraries\st_shapelib.dll`

```
SELECT SDE.ST_STARTPOINT(SHAPE) FROM ROADS_SAMPLE
```

Error:

```
ORA-28595: Extproc agent : Invalid DLL Path
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_SHAPELIB_PKG", line 325
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_OPERATORS", line 1541
28595. 00000 -  "Extproc agent : Invalid DLL Path"
*Cause:    The path of DLL supplied for the extproc execution is invalid.
*Action:   Check if the DLL path is set properly using the EXTPROC_DLLS
           environment variable.
```

However, instead of using `extproc`, I just took a shortcut by placing the `st‌​_shapelib.dll` library file directly in the Oracle `bin` folder. Oracle apparently **looks in the `bin` folder for libraries by default** (Windows only).

Comment: The servers bin directors is the start directory and therefore searched automatically on Windows.

Comment: @eckes I wonder why the Oracle documentation doesn't mention that you can simply put the `.dll` libraries in the bin folder (with Windows)? It's a much simpler method than trying to configure `extproc.ora` or `listener.ora` to reference the file elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe they don’t want you to rely on this, don’t know.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you expect that "*there must be more to it*"? `extproc.ora` simply sets environment variables for the `extproc` daemon, which is used to execute code for external stored procedures, and for procedures themselves. There is some documentation in the [application development guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_externproc.htm#ADFNS1405).

The one environment variable that seems to be recognized by `extproc` itself is `EXTPROC_DLLS` that you mention, which determines the locations where the daemon looks for shared libraries. If set to `ONLY:<path>` it won't look in `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` or `$ORACLE_HOME/lib`.

Any other variables set in `extproc.ora` are simply passed on to the environment where the external code runs, so they would be specific to each library.